# MVC C# application, date incorrect on JQuery post

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a strongly typed partial view with a date in it, like this -

```
@model Models.MyModel

MyDate: @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.MyDate)
```

With JQuery, I am posting back in the following manner -

```
var urlPost = Url.Action("MyArea", "MyController", "MySaveAction");

$.post(urlPost, form, function (returnHtml) {};
```

My controller looks like this -

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult MySaveAction(MyModel m)
{
    // My code
}
```

The other properies in the model are posting fine, but "MyDate" is not. "MyDate's" value is displayed as "1/18/2010 12:00:00 AM", but is posting back as "1/1/0001 12:00:00".
Can someone tell me why?

Thanks very much for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DisplayFor helper only displays. If you want the value to be sent to the server when you submit the form, you need to have a corresponding input field. Probably hidden in your case:

```
@model Models.MyModel

MyDate: @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.MyDate)
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.MyDate)
```